# How to encrypt a usb drive which already has data on it

Tags: encryption, disk-encryption, usb-storage

There is an external hard drive of almost 1Tb which has about 650Gb of data on it, the external HD is connected to computers via USB interface.

As far as I'm aware, this external HD is for all intents and purposes a massive USB drive. It is a data-only deposit and not an OS drive.

This USB currently has no data encryption in any form.

I have looked and looked across the internet and cannot find any guidance for how to encrypt the drive while retaining the data that is currently on it.

We cannot replace the data, and there's so much of it, that to copy it off and on back on again will be extremely time-consuming and likely will require occasional attention (rather than simply leaving it for a night). It is not USB3.0 (it's quite old).

Is there a suggested method for resolving this? In a perfect situation, a program can be downloaded or purchased and can then be applied to the USB to process through it encrypting the full disk in one slog. I fear I may have misunderstood the way USB encryption works.

What are the practical options?

Comment: Tar the whole thing and then encrypt the tar via gpg?

Comment: Encrypt each file individually, Veracrypt, Bitlocker ... I could go on ...

Comment: You research and then implement the use of whatever FDE solution, that will satisfy your requirements to protect your data, and will be supported by the operating system of your choice.

Comment: Anything you do, you risk losing your data, especially on a very old disk. I recommend to copy it even if it takes a long time, if you value your data.